# Usage of "mailing list" in corporate language

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, email, language-evolution, metonyms

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/mailing-list) defines *mailing list* as:

> a list of names and addresses kept by an organization so that it can
> send information and advertisements to the people on the list

An example sentence would be:

> I asked to be put on their mailing list.

However, in recent years I noticed a lot of people using the term *mailing list* to indicate the emails themselves, as in the following examples:

> (a) Those updates? Yes, I shared them via mailing list.
>
> (b) I'll include those snippets in the next mailing list.
>
> (c) I'm tired to receive useless mailing lists.

My questions thus are:

1. Is this usage in any way excusable?
2. What would be a better way to rephrase these sentences so that's clear the emails the speakers are referring to are being sent to a mailing list?
3. What's the name of the rhetorical figure that indicates this behaviour? Is this a metonymy?

Comment: I take example *a* to be referring to the list itself, that is, the updates were shared by using the mailing list. The other two examples are not something I've encountered, and to me they sound wrong so I wouldn't say that myself but still it's clear what is meant. Regarding your phrasing in 2, isn't "sent to a mailing list" also an incorrect use of the term? You send to the addresses on the list, not to the list itself.

Comment: (b) and (c) are wrong, I think. Emails and mailing lists are separate things.

Comment: While the dictionary definition captures the standard, traditional meaning of the phrase, it is nowadays sometimes used as a semi-technical term for whatever the software that one happens to be using labels as a mailing list. It is that sense that is probably intended in (a).

Answer (score 0):

1. Let's look at what is wrong with these sentences, where applicable.

(a) is perfectly correct, it is just very informal. The person speaking sent a message making available "those updates" *via a mailing list*, which is common colloquial speech for "using a mechanism that, for the selection of the recipients of the message, relies on a pre-defined list of recipients". Which is the very definition of a *mailing list*. Saying (a) is commonly understood in all contexts I know, unless people in a context lack a basic understanding of what a mailing list is good for at all. So unless someone is being quite nitpicky about express correctness of detail, there is nothing wrong with that.

(b) and (c) are extremely sloppy speech and, unless accepted in a group that clearly doesn't care, simply incorrect. I don't know about "permissible" - that would depend on the group in which it is used and on the (formal and informal) rules it adheres to. Anyway, saying (b) or (c) seriously just betrays either extreme sloppiness or a lack of understanding (or lack of willingness to speak correctly on a common level regarding the matter of such understanding).

2. How to repair what's wrong

(b) is easily corrected by saying, I'll include those snippets in *my next message on* that mailing list. Which might, very colloquially again, be abbreviated to, "in my next message" (not mentioning the list at all but meaning it), or, "in my next list mail" (oh well), or, "my next circular [mail] (on that list)"

(c) is, properly speaking, beyond repair in itself -- if it means what it says, that's an email system administrator continually bugged by some users sending them mailing lists (lists of recipients) that make no sense. **However**, what the speaker obviously means to say is simply, "I'm tired of getting useless mail (via certain mailing lists)".

3. I haven't heard about a meteonomy so I take the liberty to leave this as an exercise in some research in a good dictionary :D